# Issue with crypt C API on AIX 7.1

Tags: c, aix, password-encryption

I am writing a password reset utility on AIX (7.1.0.0) and I need to support SMD5, SSHA256, SSHA512 and BLOWFISH password hash algorithms. I have successfully implemented the code for SMD5, SSHA256 and SSHA512. However, for BLOWFISH algorithm the 'crypt' API still returns normal DES hash and not the BLOWFISH hash. I tried different prefixes in salt value - {sblowfish} {sblowfish}08$ {SBLOWFISH} {SBLOWFISH}08$. However, I still don't get blowfish hash. For, AIX 5.3 {sblowfish} prefix in salt value works and I get required hash. However, for AIX 7.1 it doesn't work.

```
The format for the salt value I am using is as follows -
MD5 - {smd5}<randomly generated 8 characters>$
SHA256 - {ssha256}06$<randomly generated 8 characters>$
SHA512 - {ssha512}06$<randomly generated 8 characters>$
BLOWFISH - {sblowfish}08$<randomly generated 22 characters>$
```

I then pass the user password and salt value to the 'crypt' API in 'C'.

```
    crypt(password, salt);
```

For MD5, SHA256 and SHA512 I get the password hash which is compliant to the corresponding algorithm.
However, for BLOWFISH salt, the 'crypt' API rejects the salt and instead returns normal DES hash though i have the blowfish in the system.

Can anybody please help out here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if the crypt tool has the same requirements as the PHP implementation (which calls the tool), but there the salt must be of a given alphabet: `./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. A valid salt parameter would look like `$2y$10$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veu`, containing the algorithm, the cost factor and the salt.

Comment: yes it is the same salt char set applicable for C crypt() API as well. I have provided the same.

Comment: Could you try out this call `crypt("mypassword", "$2y$10$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veu")` directly? Does it give the same error?

Comment: yes, i tried the salt provided by you..still the crypt() API returns normal DES hash. I think '2y' prefix is for SUSE.

Comment: Then it seems that is is not supported at all. You can try if "2a" is supported (also BCrypt), otherwise i'm out of ideas.

Comment: I have tried '2a' as well but the result is no different. Also looks like bcrypt() API is not available on AIX7.1.